# Flutter navigate to second screen and focus on Text field?

Tags: flutter, navigation, textfield, flutter-textinputfield

When I tap on a button I want to navigate to the second screen Focus on TextField(there is only one) and raise a keyboard.

I successfully focused when I taped on a widget on the same screen using FocusNode.

Comment: did you tried adding autofocus: true, in the TextField

Answer (score 0):

Use `autofocus: true,`

```dart
 TextField(autofocus: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

First Page :

```
class firstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  firstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<firstPage> createState() => _firstPageState();
}

class _firstPageState extends State<firstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("First Page")),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("go to second page"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SecondPage(
                            focusOnTextField: false,
                          )),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

Second page :

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage({Key? key, this.focusOnTextField}) : super(key: key);

  bool? focusOnTextField;
  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second Page")),
      body: Center(
          child: TextField(
        autofocus: widget.focusOnTextField ?? false,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```